# PostgreSQL's pg_restore error while restoring

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I took a backup of database from remote server using pg_dump from my local in directory format. The version of postgres remote server's is 9.3.23 and my postgres local version is 9.6. So, when i am trying to restore, the data gets restored but it's throwing few errors.

This is the command I used for dumping:

```
pg_dump -h 172.16.0.70 -U postgres -d enet -n finance -Fd -j5  -f fin
```

This is the command i used for restoring:

```
pg_restore -h 172.16.0.70 -U postgres -d newdb08aug19  -j5   fin
```

-- Dumped from database version 9.3.23

-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.6.14

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while INITIALIZING:
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout"

Command was: `SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;`

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "row_security"

Command was: `SET row_security = off;`

Comment: You need to use `pg_dump` from version 9.3

Comment: Should we unistall the postgres 9.6 and install postgres 9.3 or can we do it by downgrading only the pg_dump ?

Comment: Do it on 172.16.0.70 directly. If that is not possible, install 9.3 in addition to 9.6.

Comment: Yeah, So it's beacuse of version mismatch right? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: After installing 9.3 in addition to 9.6 the problem was solved. Because previously 9.3 was not present. @LaurenzAlbe